# Java Servlet not found on Google App Engine deploy

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlet

I am working on an Apache Maven dynamic web project on eclipse.  It uses static files (html, css, js) and a Java servlet.  When I deploy my project to the google app engine, the Java servlet does not handle http requests.  The project runs perfectly locally.  The servlets use @WebServlet, but adding url-mapping to the xml doesn't work either.  I deploy using mvn appengine:update.  To troubleshoot, I decided to take a java class from a [google github repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine-java8/requests/src/main/java/com/example/appengine/requests/RequestsServlet.java).  I added the java file to my servlet folder and after deploying I get 404 errors for it as well.

This is my WebServlet annotation:

```
@WebServlet(name = "requests", description = "Requests: Trivial request",
    urlPatterns = "/requests")
```

Here is the bulk of my pom.xml:

```
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.54</version>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>www</warSourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
 <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>
 <dependencies>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">

  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <runtime>java8</runtime>
  <warmup-requests-enabled>true</warmup-requests-enabled>
  <module>default</module>
  <automatic-scaling>
    <min-idle-instances>1</min-idle-instances>
    <max-idle-instances>automatic</max-idle-instances>
    <min-pending-latency>500ms</min-pending-latency>
    <max-pending-latency>automatic</max-pending-latency>
    <max-concurrent-requests>50</max-concurrent-requests>
  </automatic-scaling>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: Can you post your `appengine-web.xml`?  The production App Engine standard environment only supports Java 7 and Servlet 2.5.  [App Engine standard environment for Java 8](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8) is now in beta, but requires an explicit `<runtime>java8</runtime>` to be added to your [`appengine-web.xml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8#specifying_the_java_8_runtime_for_your_app).

Comment: @BriandeAlwis 
I updated my post.  I did have that tag included in the xml.

Comment: Finally found a moment to try to reproduce this and… it works for me.  I used your same `appengine-web.xml`, but I don't have my source in `src` and `www`, and I don't pin a version on `maven-war-plugin`.

I can only suggest you look at the "Tools" menu for in the [Developer Console > App Versions](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions) and look at the "Debug" and verify that the uploaded archive looks as you expect.  And check the logs to see what if there's anything anomalous reported.

Comment: I had the same problem, and it happens to work (locally and on deploy) when there is no web.xml file in WEB-INF. I don't know if this is a bug or intended behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue. It seems you are missing the cloud tools plugin. To resolve it, add the following on your `<plugins>`:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
   <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.1</version>
   <configuration>
      <deploy.promote>true</deploy.promote>
      <deploy.stopPreviousVersion>true</deploy.stopPreviousVersion>          
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If the above does not mitigate your issue, please post full error logs. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Servlet 3.1 annotations do not seem to work in the Local Development Server at the time I am posting this.

I got the same code to work when actually deployed to GAE, but nothing with `@WebServlet` works with the local development environment.